# How can I update topic content using Discourse API?

Tags: discourse

I have tried to use PUT `/t/:id` to update topic content with no effect.

https://github.com/discourse/discourse_api/blob/master/lib/discourse_api/api/topics.rb

Seems there is no way to update the content using API. Am I missing anything?

Comment: Would you mind accepting my answer if it helped you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to provide the topic slug like this: `PUT /t/:slug/:id` as documented here: http://docs.discourse.org/#tag/Topics%2Fpaths%2F~1t~1%7Bslug%7D~1%7Bid%7D.json%2Fput

The `/t/:id` endpoint only works if you issue a `GET` request as documented here: http://docs.discourse.org/#tag/Topics%2Fpaths%2F~1t~1%7Bid%7D.json%2Fget which I guess is not what you want.

**The solution**

> In Discourse land, a topic it's just a bunch of posts. A topic has no
>   body, the first post of the topic is the body.

So, what you do is this:

1. `GET /t/:id` with your topic id
2. Parse the `post_stream` and get the first post, or whichever you need. Get the ID
3. `PUT /posts/:id` and use the ID you just got, and provide `post[raw]` in the body.

Please, see this discussion: https://meta.discourse.org/t/updating-topic-body-via-the-api/61220/5